# Can I use the 아/어 있다 construction with 가다 / 오다?

Tags: grammar

I made a note once that the [아/어 있다](http://www.koreanwikiproject.com/wiki/%EC%95%84/%EC%96%B4_%EC%9E%88%EB%8B%A4) construction can be used with 가다 and 오다, but I can't easily find any example sentences. With 가다, would that be written '가 있다' or '가어 있다'? Would it mean that something "Is still away" (having gone)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

가 있다 is definitely possible, it can be used to mean that someone has gone somewhere and is still there right now.

Same with 와 있다, it means that someone has arrived here and is here with the speaker right now.

Examples:

> 엄마는 지금 미국 가 있는데. *Mom is in America right now.*
>
> 저리 가 있어라. *Go over there and stay there.*
>
> 여기 안 와 있는 사람이 누구지? *Who's not here right now?*
>
> 우리 집에 와 있지 그랬어. *You should have come and stayed at my house.*

Note that 가고 있다 and 오고 있다 is completely different.